# How i can get the screenshot of current page of an android application?

Tags: android, screenshot

How i can get the screenshot of current page of an android application ?? PLease anyone help me for that. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Depends what you want. Current screen of YOUR application or of any?

Comment: You want screenshot from AVD or a real Device??

Comment: in the DDMS perspective there is an option to take the picture...in the left side ....

Comment: Did you meant taking screenshot programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your device, but generally you can just press the Volume Down and Power buttons at the same time, hold them for a second, and your phone will take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on how you want to take screenshot

if you want to take screenshot from eclipse then..

**Goto DDMS->Devices->Select your Device-> click on Camera(Screen Capture) icon on Right side -> save.**

But if you want to take snapshot programmatic this answer could be useful to you..

[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android/5651242#5651242)